# Expectation of the number of uniformly random n-bit vectors such that they contain a basis of {0,1}^n?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the expectation of the cardinality of the set of uniformly random bit vectors $v_i \in \{0,1\}^n$ such it contains a basis of the space $\{0,1\}^n$?

What is an elegant way of deriving it?

Comment: How is your set chosen ?

Comment: Does that affect the answer?

Comment: Of course. Do you pick one vector, then another, etc. until it finally contains a basis ?

Comment: Yes, I add them one by one

Answer (score 1):

We imagine picking the vectors one by one and find the chance that each one creates a linear dependence.  When we pick the first vector the only one that creates a linear dependence is all $0$s, which we get with chance $2^{-n}$.  When we pick the second one there are two vectors that can create a dependence, so we fail with chance $2^{-n+1}$.  When we pick the third, assuming we haven't already created a dependence, there are four vectors that can create a dependence.  When we pick the $k^{th}$ there are $2^{k-1}$ vectors that can create a dependence.  The chance we get to the end without creating one is $$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-2^{-n+k-1}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-2^{-k}\right)$$  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%20(1-2%5E-k)%20from%201%20to%20n) evaluates this as $$\left(\frac 12;\frac 12\right)_n$$ terms of the q-Polchammer symbol.  Some values are shown below.  The limit at $n=\infty$ is about $$0.288788095086602421278899721929230780088911904840685784114...$$  The [inverse symbolic calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standardCalc) does not have another expression for this except the product I gave.
[image]

Comment: This looks fine to me, except for this concerns probabilities, while the question asked for an expectation.

Comment: @gen:  yes, I found the wording confusing.  Maybe it is intended to be the size of the last independent set as you pick vectors.  This is the chance you get all the way to $n$.  You can use my first product with a lower upper limit $m$ to compute the chance you get to $m$, then the chance you end at $m$ is the probability you get to $m$ minus the probability you get to $m+1$.  Multiply each of those by $m$ and add.  It doesn't look to me like it will be nice.